# magento 1.9.2.3 security checks

Tags: magento-1.9

After each month i saw some junk files on server where magento 1.9.2.3 is installed , How can I safe my magento store from malware attacks.

Comment: Have you installed security patches on your site ?

Comment: I don't have any idea about security patches. can you please explain these?

Comment: Please follow what I have shared you.

Comment: @khaild bashir to resolve security patch error see my answer

Answer (score 1):

[Check Site -](https://www.magereport.com/) what patches your site need for security

From this url you will find, which patches you need, then you have to install those patches from magento official site. Then your site will be perfectly secured from all malware attacks.

For more details follow this - https://magecomp.com/blog/how-to-install-magento-security-patches/

```
To install patches -
1))  ssh user@sitedomain
2))  cd sitedomain
3))  ls comaand
4)) bash PATCH_name
5))   To resolve Erorr ------> Run these 4 commands

$ php -f shell/compiler.php -- disable
$ php -f shell/compiler.php -- clear
$ php -f shell/compiler.php -- compile
$ php -f shell/compiler.php -- enable
```

Comment: Check Site giving "Security patch 8788" not patched error. how to resolve this?

Comment: pls share screenshot

Comment: https://gyazo.com/97d9822496bc0aafdc7666ce3fba0f89

Comment: Yes this is what I am saying, like this you will get many more patches to install in your site for security.

Answer (score 0):

Magento security encourages the use of these RULES  https://github.com/gwillem/magento-malware-scanner which include full instructions for installation. This article provides additional information on how to setup your site to use the malware self-scanning tool.

Install Git for your server or local machine by following the instructions located here: GIT INSTALLATION INSTRUCTIONS https://help.github.com/articles/set-up-git/

If you are using Debian/Ubuntu machine or server, use the following to install required packages:
sudo apt install yara python3

If you are using MacOs, you can install yara using Homebrew

Install Xcode
`xcode-select –install`

Install Homebrew
`ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"`

Install python and yara
`brew install yara python3`

Installing the Malware Scanning Tool
Once you have completed installing Git and python you will need to download the malware tool and scan your Magento site using the following commands:

Clone the malware repository from GitHub
git clone https://github.com/gwillem/magento-malware-scanner.git

Validate Malware Signatures and Samples
`python tools/runtests.py`

Scannning Magento Files and Site
The Yara scanner works only on files and directories. Many types of malware hide in the database and are only displayed when accessing the site. To scan those locations, you need to download the site homepage to the same directory that will be scanned. Make sure to NOT put those files into a publicly accessible directory and to remove them after scanning. Steps to scan these locations include:

Download your site homepage for scanning analysis
`curl –o output.html http://yoursite.com`

Create dump of the database – details are described HERE (and you can find database connection details in your Magento app/etc/local.xml file)

Scan the Magento site for Malware
`cd magento-malware-collection`
`yara -r rules/all-confirmed.yar yara -r rules/all-confirmed.yar site-index-and-sql-dump-folder/`

Viewing Malware Results
If malware is discovered by the malware tool you will see similar output in your command window:

`scanner@m1:~/magento-malware-collection$
yara -r rules/all-confirmed.yar /Users/scanner/code/m1vg/ 2> /dev/null
visbot /Users/scanner/code/m1vg/app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/onepage.phtml
jquery_code_su /Users/scanner/code/m1vg/app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/onepage.phtml
scanner@m1:~/magento-malware-collection$`

Reviewing Malware Results Checklist
If the scan confirms your site has been impacted by malware, Magento recommends that you check your site for other issues using MAGEREPORT.COM, a free service that provides insight into your security status. Work with your Solution Partner or developer to clean your site and follow our recommended site remediation steps.

Deploy any missing security patches and address other issues discovered by the MAGEREPORT.COM scan. Enterprise Edition patches are available in My Account and Community Edition patches are posted on the Community Edition download page under the Release Archive tab.

**Source: https://magento.com/security/best-practices/detect-malware-new-discovery-rules**

After cleanup install all latest Magento Security Patches, release tab:

https://magento.com/tech-resources/download

Answer (score 0):

"Security patch 8788" not patched error. to resolve it

delete file in skin\adminhtml\default\default\media folder for